# react errno 1 failed at the jamming@0.1.0 start script

Tags: reactjs

This may have been asked before however I am trying to open the devleopment site on chrome for my webpage but are getting this issue:

```
code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jamming@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jamming@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

This is happening when I type `npm start` in the command line.

I have no issues opening it on the macbook I created the react file but I am trying to open this on a seperate Mac where I am facing this issue. The files are saved in Icloud so can access on both computers but doesn't appear to show the same information.

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks